# Network Printer Issue

Tags: printer

I have a Windows-7 Desktop at office. There is a network printer Dell MFP2335dn which is installed on this dekstop. The printer worked fine for me(I could print from my desktop), sometime back but recently I have not been able to print. When I give a print job, it stays in the queue for a long time, nothing gets printed. When I check the status of the printer in "Devices and Printers", it says - Offline.

I removed the printer installed on my Desktop, and tried to install the drivers downloaded from [Dell website](http://support.euro.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=uk&l=en&s=gen&releaseid=R241894&formatcnt=0&libid=0&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=349205) but to no avail.

Comment: This really belongs on superuser.

Comment: Have you checked the connection between the computer and the printer and made sure the printer is turned on with a ready status?

Comment: @joeqwerty:Printer is on, ready. The printer is networked printer, not local to my desktop. And my computer can see the printer if i type its address httP://192.168.96.54 in my browser. There i can see if that status is Ready.

Comment: OK. Have you tried rebooting your computer?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you can pull up the printer's web interface, the printer itself may only be usable for printing through a print server (depending on how it was set up).  It's possible that these settings have changed between the time you were able to print to it and now.  Your easiest route is likely to find someone who can currently print to it, and copy their settings.

It's possible you'll need to have permissions added to print to it, so you might literally not be able to use that printer until you've talked to someone in IT.

(I could see this fitting either here or SU, but the votes can have it)